# bash merge multiple lines

Tags: bash

I have a file looks like:

```
id001 success:100
id002 success:99
id002 failed:1
id003 failed:100
id004 success:50
id004 failed:50
```

I want to format it as:

```
id001 success:100
id002 success:99 failed:1
id003 failed:100
id004 success:50 failed:50
```

Could someone give me a solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk '{a[$1]=a[$1] FS $2}END{for(i in a) print i,a[i]}' file
```

Alternative Ruby(1.9+)

```
$ ruby -ane 'BEGIN{a=Hash.new};a[$F[0]]="#{a[$F[0]]} #{$F[1]}"; END{ a.each{|x,y| puts "#{x}#{y}" }}' file
```

Comment: Your awk solution output does not match OP's output. Extra space.

Answer (score 2):

Using 'awk':

```
awk '{line[$1] = line[$1] " " $2}
     END { for (id in line) { printf "%s%s\n", id, line[id] } }'
```

Answer (score 1):

It's short (but cryptic) in sed:

```
sed '$!N;/^\([^ ]*\) .*\n\1/{s/\n[^ ]* / /;};P;D' file
```

Comment: nice but, input needs to be sorted first.

Answer (score 0):

Without using `awk` (just for the fun of it):

```
for i in `grep -o "id[0-9]*" myfile`; do
   echo -n "$i "
   grep $i myfile | cut -c 7- |xargs
done | uniq
```

Comment: First pass, you `grepped` the ids from the file. then you iterate through these ids, each time calling grep again on these ids. Plus chaining to `cut` and xargs (extra processes). Imagine if the file is big :)

Comment: @kurumi: It was a rhetorical question :) but I can move that `uniq` to the first `grep` :p

Comment: doesn't matter. you are still calling grep again for each id iterated. like i said already,  if your myfile is BIG and you have several ids (eg 100 unique ids) to go through, then you are calling grep 100 times .... on that BIG file... :)

Answer (score 0):

Didn't see any Perl answers. So here you go:

```
perl -lnae '$h{$F[0]}.="$F[1] ";END{print "$_ $h{$_}"for(sort keys %h)}' file
```

[**See it on Ideone**](http://www.ideone.com/4BtCB)

Comment: -lnae is not easy to remember, i prefer -lean :)