# Using AWK to merge unique rows based on column one

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed, text-processing

I am trying to write an AWK script to summarize data on a large text file. The order of the resulting data is important so i can't use sort.

I have tried different variations of FNR==NR but haven't had any luck

**Input file**

```
Height 3.5
Weight 12.3
Age 23
: 
:
Height 4.5
Weight 15.5
Age 31
:
:
```

**Expected Output**

```
Height 3.5 4.5
Weight 12.3 15.5
Age 23 31
```

Comment: please provide your attempt

Answer (score 5):

With awk:

```
awk '{a[$1]=a[$1] FS $2} END{for(i in a) print i a[i]}' file
```

Output:

```
Weight 12.3 15.5
Height 3.5 4.5
:     
Age 23 31
```

Derived from: [how to merge rows that share unique IDs into a comma separated table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31278711/3776858)

---

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Answer (score 0):

Using [awk's array](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Arrays.html) you can group the values.

This is a simplified version:.

```
BEGIN {
summary["Weight"] = "Weight";
...
}
{
summary[$1] = summary [$1] " " $2
}
END {
print summary["Weight"];
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not awk but might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 'H;g;s/((\n\S+)[^\n]*)(.*)\2(.*)/\1\4\3/;h;$!d;x;s/.//' file
```

Use the hold space to gather up the results for each key and at end-of-file, remove the introduced newline and print the results.