# Long to Wide Format

Tags: bash, parsing, variables, awk, format

In bash (perhaps using awk), I want to convert a table in long format to wide. For simplicity:

Input:

```
A one
A two
A three
B seven
B eight
B nine
```

Output:

```
A one,two,three
B seven,eight,nine
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: See: [Using AWK to merge unique rows based on column one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56716292/3776858)

Answer (score 1):

One way, using [GNU datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/):

```
$ datamash -W -g1 collapse 2 < input.txt
A   one,two,three
B   seven,eight,nine
```

(This does require that the file be sorted on the first column like in your example. If not, add `-s` to the options).

Another way, using `perl`, which supports more complicated data structures than `awk` to make storing a list of items easier:

```
$ perl -lane 'push @{$groups{$F[0]}}, $F[1];
              END { $" = ",";
                    for $g (sort keys %groups) { print "$g\t@{$groups{$g}}" }}' input.txt
A   one,two,three
B   seven,eight,nine
```

(Doesn't require sorted input)