# Modify a Line after Matching Pattern with Another Line, Then Delete the Other Line with Awk

Tags: awk, command-line

For example, say I had the following lines:

```
1,r,other,columns,....,
4,w,...,
2,w,etc...
3,r
1,w
2,r
```

I would want my output written to a file (or overwrite the existing file) as:

```
1,r/w,other,columns,....,
4,w,...,
2,r/w,etc...
3,r
```

Where order does not matter in the end.

The first "row" of the line where commas are delimiters are the patterns to match, once matched, one will have 'r' and the other 'w' as their second row, I want to combine them into one line like the example above.

**Update**

I've managed to get it working with the command:

```
awk -F, '{a[$1]=a[$1]?a[$1] OFS $2:$2} END{for (i in a) print i FS a[i]}' OFS="/" file
```

However, this erases all other columns that come after the second, how can I preserve those columns?

Comment: Closest question I found: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56716292/using-awk-to-merge-unique-rows-based-on-column-one try to adapt it for your use case and ask if you are stuck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
{
    key = $1
    perms[key] = (key in perms ? perms[key] "/" : "") $2
}
$3 != "" {
    sub(/([^,]*,){2}/,"")
    vals[key] = $0
}
END {
    for (key in perms) {
        print key, perms[key] (key in vals ? OFS vals[key] : "")
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
1,r/w,other,columns,....,
2,w/r,etc...
3,r
4,w,...,
```