# merge rows with identical column values

Tags: bash

I'm a beginner in bash. I have a .csv file. It contains 2 columns (Name and Num). Here is the content of columns:

```
Name,Num 
ex1,10.20.30.40 
ex2,20.30.40.30 
ex3,10.45.60.20 
ex4,10.20.30.40
ex5,20.30.40.30
```

I want to merge the rows that their 2nd column is identical. For example here I have 2 rows that their 2nd column is "10.20.30.40". I want the output to be like this:

```
Name,Num 
ex1 ex4,10.20.30.40 
ex2 ex5,20.30.40.30 
ex3,10.45.60.20
```

so the name column of the first row contains both ex1 and ex2. I searched a lot and all I find was how to sort lines based on their 2nd column:

```
echo $(awk -F ',' '{print $2}' name.csv | sort) >> sub2.csv
```

but it only sorts and prints the second column to "sub2.csv".

I also tried this script:

```
echo $(awk -F',' '{k=$2;if(a[k])a[k]=a[k] OFS $1;else{a[k]=$0;b[++i]=k}}
           END{for(x=1;x<=i;x++)print a[b[x]]}' name.csv) >> sub2.csv
```

but the output is confusing (for example rows are not separated).

Would you please guide me about how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=","} NR==1{print;next} {a[$2]=$2 in a ? a[$2] " " $1 : $1} END{for(i in a) print a[i] "," i}' file
```

Output:

```
Name,Num 
ex1 ex4,10.20.30.40
ex2 ex5,20.30.40.30
ex3,10.45.60.20
```

Derived from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31283693/3776858

See: [4 Awk If Statement Examples ( if, if else, if else if, **:?** )](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/02/awk-conditional-statements/)

Comment: Thanks. Since I want to add the results to a new file (sub2.csv), should I write it like this: "echo $(awk 'BEGIN{FS=","} NR==1{print;next} {a[$2]=$2 in a ? a[$2] " " $1 : $1} END{for(i in a) print a[i] "," i}' name.csv) >> sub2.csv" ?

Comment: @Pablo: use this to append awk's output to file sub2.csv: `awk 'BEGIN{FS=","} NR==1{print;next} {a[$2]=$2 in a ? a[$2] " " $1 : $1} END{for(i in a) print a[i] "," i}' name.csv >> sub2.csv`

Comment: Your script correctly prints the values, but when I append the output to the .csv file using the script I mentioned in the first comment, all results are written in 1 raw with separate columns. I wanted each Number and its corresponding names on separate rows...

Comment: @Pablo: Don't use `echo $(awk ...) >> sub2.csv` use `awk ... >> sub2.csv`

Comment: One more question: In case I want to separate names in a raw with newline character, should I change a[$2] " " $1 with a[$2] "\n" $1?

Comment: @Pablo: Try to replace `"$\n"` with `RS`. See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, **RS**, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Comment: Thanks. In case I have another column after the 2nd column, how can I edit this code to display the third column too? This code only displays column1 and column2 as I have asked in my question. Which part should I change to display the third column too?

Comment: @Pablo: I suggest to start a complete new question.